# Updated Metadata not showing while sharing link on Facebook in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm updating the metadata of the angular 8 website for dynamic content using the addTag() and updateTag() of angular. These functions update the metadata (og:description, og:image, og:title etc.) as I can see in the inspect section but when I'm sharing it on Facebook it doesn't show the updated metadata. Anyone can help me with this? I tried angular universal too but that also didn't work.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem in Angular 11.